# Python 3.3 pygame 1.9.2a0 (64-bit) graphics window displays 1st image but then freezes

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

Using Python 2.7.3 and Pygame on a classroom PC, I created a movie-quote guessing game using both the command prompt window (to interact with the user) and a graphics window (to display still .png files, such as photos from movies).  The game ran successfully.

Now I want to run and enhance the game on my own Windows 7 64-bit PC.  I downloaded Python version 3.3.5 and pygame-1.9.2a0.win-amd64-py3.3.exe.  Then I made two changes to my game code to adjust from Python 2.7.3 to Python 3.3.5 environment:  (1) deleted "raw_" from "raw_input()" commands; and (2) deleted 1st line, which instructor had told us to use so that Python 2.6 would act like later versions:  "from **future** import division, absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals".

Now, on my PC, the command prompt window and the audio both work fine.  The pygame graphics window displays only first .png image.  Top of window (next to pygame logo) immediately says "(Not Responding)".  There are no error messages.  Thank you for any help.

Here's the code:

```
# Import common modules
import pygame, pygame.mixer, os
from pygame.locals import *

# Initialize pygame, window and sound mixer
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,450))
pygame.display.set_caption('Greatest Movie Lines')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
pygame.mixer.init()

# Create and display background
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((250, 250, 250))
screen.blit(background, (0,0)) 

# Initialize variables that will persist through entire game
gameRunning = True  
roundsCompleted = 0
totalRoundsAvailable = 5   
scoreSoFar = 0
quitOrContinue = 'Try another movie line?  Type y or n: '

def beginGame():
    titleDisplay = pygame.image.load('titleSlide.png')
    titleDisplay = pygame.transform.scale(titleDisplay, (600, 450))
    screen.blit(titleDisplay, (0,0)) 
    pygame.display.flip()
    sound = pygame.mixer.music.load('20fox-fanfare-w-cinemascope-ext_anewman.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    print('First, move the photo window rightwards and make this black window')
    print('smaller so that you can see both windows completely (no overlap).')
    print(     )
    doneFixingWindow = input('When done repositioning windows, hit enter here.')

    howToPlay = pygame.image.load('howToPlay.png')
    howToPlay = pygame.transform.scale(howToPlay, (600, 450))
    screen.blit(howToPlay, (0,0)) 
    pygame.display.flip()

    print(     )
    print('Read the instructions at right.')
    doneFixingWindow = input('Then hit enter to play!')
    print(     )

def endGame():
    endDisplay = pygame.image.load('ending.png')
    endDisplay = pygame.transform.scale(endDisplay, (600, 450))
    screen.blit(endDisplay, (0,0)) 
    pygame.display.flip()
    sound = pygame.mixer.music.load('warnerbros_fanfare.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    print('    ')
    print('Game over.  Thank you for playing.')
    raw_input('Hit enter to exit the game.')


def playRound(cumScoreLastRound,roundsDone):
    # Initialize variables and constants used in the game rounds
    hintUsed = False
    guessOrHint = 'Would you like to (g)uess or get a(h)int first? Type g or h:  ' 
    requestGuess = 'Guess the movie line (no commas):  '
    noKeywordsMatched = "Sorry, your guess didn't match any keywords."
    oneKeywordMatched = 'Not bad.  You got one keyword right:'
    twoKeywordsMatched = 'Pretty good!  You got two keywords right:'
    threeKeywordsMatched = 'Great! You got all three keywords:'

    # Load variables specific to this round
    fo = open("quoteData.csv","r")
    movieData = fo.readlines()
    line = movieData[roundsDone + 1]
    movie = line.split(",")
    droodle = pygame.image.load(movie[3])
    droodle = pygame.transform.scale(droodle, (600, 450))
    hint = movie[4]
    keyword1 = movie[5]
    keyword2 = movie[6]
    keyword3 = movie[7]
    answer = pygame.image.load (movie[8])
    answer = pygame.transform.scale(answer, (600, 450))

    # Initialize counters specific to this round
    keywordMatches = 0                                                  
    keyword1Yes = ' '
    keyword2Yes = ' '
    keyword3Yes = ' '   

    # Display this round's droodle 
    screen.blit(droodle, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    print()
    print('Here is the droodle portraying a famous movie line.')

    # Give user option of hint before guessing
    playerChoice = input(guessOrHint)

    while playerChoice != 'g' and playerChoice != 'h':   # Ensure valid selection
            print('    ')
        print('Not a valid selection')
        playerChoice = input(guessOrHint)

    if playerChoice == 'h':     # Display hint if player chooses to see one
        print('    ')
        print('Hint: ',hint)
        hintUsed = True

    # Solicit and evaluate the player's guess   
    print(   )
    guess = str.lower(input(requestGuess))              

    guessParsed = guess.split() # Determine which keywords match, if any
        if word == keyword1:
            keyword1Yes = keyword1
            keywordMatches = keywordMatches + 1
        if word == keyword2:
            keyword2Yes = keyword2
            keywordMatches = keywordMatches + 1
        if word == keyword3:
            keyword3Yes = keyword3
            keywordMatches = keywordMatches + 1

    # Display and play the correct answer
    screen.blit(answer, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    if roundsDone == 0:
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('casab.wav') 
        sound.play()
    elif roundsDone == 1:
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('oz6.wav')   
        sound.play()
    elif roundsDone == 2:
        sound = pygame.mixer.music.load('WaterfrontClass.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()       
    elif roundsDone == 3:
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('offer.wav') 
        sound.play()
    else:
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gwtw.wav')      
        sound.play()

    # Calculate score for this round and new total score
    if keywordMatches == 0:
        scoreThisRound = 0
    if keywordMatches == 1:
        scoreThisRound = 25
    if keywordMatches == 2:
        scoreThisRound = 50
    if keywordMatches == 3:
        scoreThisRound = 100
    if hintUsed == True:
        scoreThisRound = scoreThisRound - 20
    newCumScore = cumScoreLastRound + scoreThisRound


    # Display player's result, score for round, and cumulative score
    print('    ')
    if keywordMatches == 0:
        print(noKeywordsMatched, keyword1Yes, keyword2Yes, keyword3Yes)
    if keywordMatches == 1:
        print(oneKeywordMatched, keyword1Yes, keyword2Yes, keyword3Yes)
    if keywordMatches == 2:
        print(twoKeywordsMatched, keyword1Yes, keyword2Yes, keyword3Yes)
    if keywordMatches == 3:
        print(threeKeywordsMatched, keyword1Yes, keyword2Yes, keyword3Yes)
    print('Your score for this round is ', scoreThisRound)
    print( 'Your new total score is ', newCumScore)

    return newCumScore

while gameRunning:      

    # To begin game, display title page and instructions
    if roundsCompleted == 0:
        beginGame()

    # Play the round 
    scoreSoFar = playRound(scoreSoFar,roundsCompleted)

    # Check to see if any rounds left to be played
    roundsCompleted = roundsCompleted + 1
    if roundsCompleted == totalRoundsAvailable: 
       # End game if no rounds left to play
        print()
        input('That was our last quote.  Hit enter to exit the game.')
        endGame()
        gameRunning = False

    # Ask player whether to continue 
    else:
        print('    ')
        playerContinue = input(quitOrContinue)

        while playerContinue != 'y' and playerContinue != 'n':  # Ensure valid selection
        print('    ')
        print('Not a valid selection')
        playerContinue = input(quitOrContinue)

        if playerContinue == 'n':    # End game if player wants to quit
            endGame()
            gameRunning = False

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

PyGame is an event-driven system. If you're not using its internal event loop to drive your game, you still need to let it take some time occasionally to process internal events, like windows being moved or resized. There's a function specifically for this: [`pygame.event.pump`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump).

I think you can get your screen to be responsive if you put a call to that function in your code in a few places (perhaps just before or after you collect input on the console).